# How to correctly address resource for C# Cmdlet helpmessage localization

Tags: c#, powershell, localization, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to activate localization for parameters in my Cmdlets developed for PowerShell 5.

I have this parameter, which I'm trying to localize by supplying the values for the helpmessage as seen in this screenshot:

[image: Parameter definition in Cmdlet-Class]

And this resource-file (you can see the namespace and class name to the left):

[image: Resourcefile location and namespace]

The definition in the resource file looks like this:

[image: Definition of resource-string in resource-designer]

However, when I start powershell with the module loaded and entering Get-Help Add-IdpClient -full, the detailed information is missing the string:

[image: Missing string in get-help of powershell cmdlet]

It seems I can't figure out how to correctly address the resource for powershell to find it. What did I do wrong?